# Swagger codegen, custom code and new stub

Tags: python, swagger, flask-restful, swagger-codegen, connexion

I am tinkering with Swagger Codegen for Python and the Petstore example. I see that the generated stubs rely on Python libraries (`swagger_sever`, `connexion`,...).

```
import connexion
import six

from swagger_server.models.api_response import ApiResponse  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.category import Category  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.pet import Pet  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.tag import Tag  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server import util

def add_pet(body):  # noqa: E501
    """Add a new pet to the store

    Add a new pet to the store # noqa: E501

    :param body: Create a new pet in the store
    :type body: dict | bytes

    :rtype: Pet
    """
    if connexion.request.is_json:
        body = Pet.from_dict(connexion.request.get_json())  # noqa: E501
    return 'do some magic!'
```

This is fine, but how do I handle the scenario where:

1. I generate the stubs with CodeGen
2. I manually add my custom Python logic to implement the actual API (i.e. doing MY MAGIC),
3. I make changes to the YAML file and need to regenerate the stub.

I imagine the question is: what's the best practice to regenerate the stub and superimpose code that was implemented in the old stub?

Hopefully my question makes sense.

Comment: Any takers? 
I implemented my nice Python/Flask/Connexion endpoints on top of the codegened code base. Along the way I realized I'd happily change a few minor aspects of the API, but if I do, how do I "merge" the new "scaffolding" with the code I have already created?
I ma sure others have had the issue before and have experience they can share.

Comment: Have you been able to figure this out?  I've seen multiple similar question around the net and none of them are answered.

Comment: Not really, albeit I have a little first-hand experience to share that's not worth a whole answer, but that might be worth expanding in a comment. I did discover along the way that one of my endpoints needed to be changed slightly. I went looking for the "offending" string, and it was nowhere to be found in the codegened source. Turns out changing it in my YAML. rerunning the codegen and manually overwriting the YAML file in the `swagger/` folder was enough to do the trick. In short, the generated code still performs a ton of introspection on the "tweaked" source YAML file. I say TWEAKED bcs

Comment: I say TWEAKED YAML file because overwriting my own YAML file was not good enough (some consistency checks went off and the server wouldn't start). I had to run codegen again separately with the new YAML, find the tweaked YAML, and manually grab the tweaked file and place it in the code base I had been working on. It worked for me, but of course you are in unchartered territory once you start doing something like that.

Comment: @Lucia-p  Thanks for the reply.  One more question...  Where are you adding your business logic to the server stubs?  I was hoping to add it to the express middleware via app.use() and modify the server stubs as little as possible but that's not working.

Comment: First thing first, I am using Python/Flask for my server, not Express, Anyway, I imagine the general problem is the same. I am doing something that is not very pretty. Essentially, I originally used the codegen to jump start my server, but from then on, I did things manually, My API is simple enough. When I modify that YAML, I codegen a new set of stubs in a separate folder, manually copy the new method signatures in my models and, finally, I manually tweak my code to align with the new signature. Not pretty but it has worked for me. Would love to hear from someone who knows better strategies.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to inherit the connexion generated models, and implement your logic in the child class. Then you can regenerate base models without affecting your own code. Of course you can still break it ;).

```py
import connexion
import six

from swagger_server.models.api_response import ApiResponse  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.category import Category  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.pet import Pet  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server.models.tag import Tag  # noqa: E501
from swagger_server import util

class PetInterface(Pet):

    def bark(self, stuff: str):
        return f"bark bark {stuff}"


def add_pet(body):  # noqa: E501
    """Add a new pet to the store

    Add a new pet to the store # noqa: E501

    :param body: Create a new pet in the store
    :type body: dict | bytes

    :rtype: PetInterface
    """
    if connexion.request.is_json:
        body = PetInterface.from_dict(connexion.request.get_json())  # noqa: E501
    return body.bark("here you go")
```

Use this child class in your application/controller whenever you need to interact with this model.

Comment: This is a nice suggestion, albeit it wouldn't have helped me much as the signatures of the codegened methods would change with changes to the YAML. Thank you for taking the time to write this, anyway.